# bash/csh - echo the strings "$#argv" and "#!/bin/csh"

Tags: bash, echo, sh, csh

I am trying to create a `csh` on the fly with another `csh` script by `echo`ing a bunch of statements onto another file and running it.

But I am not able to echo strings like `"$#argv"` and `"#!/bin/csh"`

The first is always parsed by the generator csh into its value of `#argv` and the `shebang` just gives an error saying `Event not found`. Is there any way that I could echo these to a file?

I am ok with the generator `csh` to be `bash` instead but the output script must be csh as it uses a whole bunch of csh environment variables.

PS - I tried echo -e and tried adding backslashes wherever I can but in vain. It also did not work when using single quotes instead of double.

Comment: Environment variables aren't really specific to any one shell. If the variable is in your environment, it will be in the environment of any child process (and if that child is a shell, available as a variable assuming the name is a valid identifier).

Comment: @chepner I did not know that! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`csh`** - similar to POSIX-like shells - **uses *single*-quoted strings (`'...'`) for *literal* strings** (strings that aren't subject to shell expansions) - in contrast with ***double*-quoted strings (`"..."`), in which `$`-prefixed references are *expanded* (interpolated, instantly)**.

Therefore, the following command should work:

```
% echo '$#argv'
#argv
```

However, **interpretation of `!`** - a command-history feature - *precedes* even the usual shell expansions, and therefore **needs an additional layer of escaping with `\`**:

```
% echo '#\!/bin/csh'
#!/bin/csh
```

Additionally - again, as in POSIX-like shells - **you can *mix* quoting styles in directly adjacent tokens** to **form a *single, composite* string**:

```
% set arg = 3
% echo 'if($#argv < '"$arg"') then'
if($#argv < 3) then
```

Note how *only* `$arg` was expanded (interpolated), due to being (the only part) enclosed in `"..."`.

In this particular case, *unquoted* use of `$arg` would have worked too, but note that **use of *unquoted* (sub)strings containing *pattern metacharacters* (such as `*` and `?`)** - yet again, as in POSIX-like shells - **makes the (whole) string subject to *globbing* (filename expansion)**.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks!

Comment: @VivekVK: My pleasure; glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `echo` with escapes to get that output from `csh`:

```
echo '$#argv'
echo '#\!/bin/csh"
```

as per the following transcript:

```
% cat testprog.csh
echo '$#argv'
echo '#\!/bin/csh'

% csh testprog.csh
$#argv
#!/bin/csh
%
```

Comment: thanks! Your test case works but it doesn't when I use it like this:  `echo  "if('$#argv' < $arg ) then"` where $arg is a local variable that needs to be replaced by its value while $#argv should not be.